# AWS Batch Trigger a spring boot microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr, aws-batch

I have below 2 requirements can you please help share any suggestion

1. AWS Batch trigger a ECR Fargate ( On demand )
2. AWS Batch trigger a Spring App deployed in ECR ( running permanently)

SO here Option 1, I need to start a spring boot app which should start in ECR Fargate. this I understood from AWS batch we can specify the Cluster of the Fargate so that when the AWS batch run the app will get started.

For Option 2, I have a spring boot App deployed in ECR Fargate and it will be running, and inside spring batch is there, Now AWS batch need to trigger the spring batch. it is possible if so can you please share the implementation sample.

Also from my client App or program I need to update the AWS batch, saying the job is success or failure. can you share any sample for those as well.

Comment: I think you mean ECS Fargate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Batch only executes ECS tasks not ECS services. For option 1 - to launch a container (your app that does the work you want) within ECS Fargate, you would  need to specify an AWS Batch compute environment as Fargate, a job queue that references the compute environment, and a job definition of the task (what container to run, what command to send, what CPU and memory resources are required). See the [Learn AWS Batch workshop](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/81ff4a6e-0a3c-41d4-be17-6ffc942d6451/en-US) or the AWS Batch [Getting Started documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/Batch_GetStarted.html) for more information on this.

For option 2 - AWS Batch and Spring Batch are orthogonal solutions. You should just call the Spring Batch API endpoint directly OR rely on AWS Batch. Using both is not recommended unless this is something you don't have control over.

But to answer your question - calling an non-AWS API endpoint is handled in your container and application code. AWS Batch does not prevent this but you would need to make sure that the container has secure access to the proper credentials to call the Spring boot app. Once your Batch job calls the API you have two choices:

1. Immediately exit and track the status of the spring batch operations elsewhere (i.e. The Batch job is to call the API and SUCCESS = "able to send the API request successfully, FAIL = "not able to call the API" )
2. Call the API, then enter a loop where you poll the status of the Spring batch job until it completes successfully or not, exiting the AWS Batch job with the same state as the Spring batch job did.